# Associating members through referrals - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activerecord

I have used Devise to create a referral tracking system similar to this [article](http://danvoell.com/dev/2013/06/simple-affiliate-and-referral-tracking-with-devise-in-rails-with-a-hint-of-cookies-and-session-variables/).

I have added 2 columns to the Members table: `refer:string` and `referral_code:string`. When a user registers, a unique string is created for them and saved in `refer` to be used later as their referral code, when they register and are using a referral link, the referer's `refer` code gets saved to the refered member's `referral_code` field.

The problem that I have is Associating the refer and referral_code, so that the person that referred can see a list of all the members that signed up with their refer code.

I need assistance with the query, in order to associate refer and referral_code for the 2 members.

For example:

- member_1 `refer:EeFfGg` `referral_code:HhIiJj`
- member_2 `refer:ZzYyWw` `referral_code:EeFfGg`
- member_3 `refer:TtUuVv` `referral_code:EeFfGg`

So member_1 needs to be able to see members 2 and 3 in his list of referrals as they both signed up with his refer code.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  def members_referred
    Members.where(referral_code: refer)
  end

end
```

This lets you do...

```
my_member.members_referred
```

...for a list of all members my_member referred

So if you have an instance variable `@member` for the view where the member sees his own profile, the view might be...

```
<% @member.members_referred each do |referred_member| %>
  <%= referred_member.name %><br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm getting an undefined local variable error, even tested the query through console:
`irb(main):001:0> Member.where(referral_code: refer)
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'refer' for main:Object`

Comment: No look at the context... the method  should be defined in class Member...  app/models/member.rb

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczyn, bear with me please, I'm a bit of a newbie. Once I have added the method to Member, how can I call this from another Controller, would I need to use an `each` iteration in the view? **Note:** this is not for the Admin's view but for the end users to see in each of their profiles?

Comment: Yes, you'd use an each iteration... I have edited my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

    def members_referred
        Members.where(referral_code: self.refer)
    end

end
```

should do the trick.